# Not able to install angular cli in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, node-modules

I'm trying to install angular in my AWS EC2 instance, while executing this command `npm install -g @angular/cli` i'm getting below error message:

```
[root@<my-ip> ec2-user]# npm install -g @angular/cli
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.5.5 -> 8.6.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.6.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.6.0 to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.8.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
npm ERR! sh: node: command not found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-05T19_01_04_592Z-debug-0.log
```

I followed below steps to install the Angular in my EC2 instance:

**Step 1:** Launch new EC2 instance using this AMI - `Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM) - Kernel 5.10, SSD Volume Type - ami-0c02fb55956c7d316 (64-bit x86) / ami-03190fe20ef6b1419 (64-bit Arm)`

**Step 2:** Installed Node using below commands:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install node
```

**Step 3:** Install Angular using this command - `npm install -g @angular/cli`

After executing the `npm install -g @angular/cli` - got the above mentioned error message.

Could someone please help what I'm doing wrong here, how can I fix this issue.

Appreciated your help in advance!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked path of your node with `which node`?  You might need to export the path or you could go to the directory where the above command points to and run the installation again.

Comment: my node is installed in this path - `root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.8.0/bin/` I tried executing `npm install -g @angular/cli` inside this directory but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: When you run `nvm run node --version` and then `nvm which $version(from the previous command)` , does it give the path you mentioned? Also, can you also paste the complete log found `/root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-05T19_01_04_592Z-debug-0.log`?